FutureBuilder not showing News list tile
I am trying to show the Fetch Items via the News List tile in my app project, but it seems no data is showing. it is still stuck on 'Streams still loading' and I don't know what is going on.
so I will present all the relevant classes.
This is the stories bloc and Stories Provider class.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_flutter/src/blocs/stories_bloc.dart';

export 'stories_bloc.dart';

class StoriesProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final StoriesBloc bloc;

  StoriesProvider({required Key super.key, required super.child})
      : bloc = StoriesBloc();

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(oldWidget) => true;

  static StoriesBloc of(BuildContext context) {
    final StoriesProvider? provider =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<StoriesProvider>();
    if (provider == null) {
      throw FlutterError('StoriesProvider not found in widget tree');
    }
    return provider.bloc;

    // return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(aspect: StoriesProvider)
    //         as StoriesProvider)
    //     .bloc;
  }
}

Stories_bloc class:
import 'package:new_flutter/src/resources/repository.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

import '../models/item_model.dart';

class StoriesBloc {
  final Repository _repository = Repository();
  final _topIds = PublishSubject<List<int>>();
  final _itemsOutput = BehaviorSubject<Map<int, Future<ItemModel?>>>();
  final _itemsFetcher = PublishSubject<int>();

  ///Getters to Streams
  Stream<List<int>> get topIds => _topIds.stream;

  Stream<Map<int, Future<ItemModel?>>> get items => _itemsOutput.stream;

  ///Getters to Sinks
  Function(int) get fetchItem => _itemsFetcher.sink.add;

  StoriesBloc() {
    _itemsFetcher.stream.transform(_itemsTransformer()).pipe(_itemsOutput);
  }

  fetchTopIds() async {
    final ids = await _repository.fetchTopIds();
    _topIds.sink.add(ids);
  }

  _itemsTransformer() {
    return ScanStreamTransformer(
      (Map<int, Future<ItemModel?>> cache, int id, _) {
        cache[id] = _repository.fetchItems(id);
        return cache;
      },
      <int, Future<ItemModel>>{},
    );
  }
}

then now I will show you the news list and news liste tile classes respectfully:
this is the news list tile class:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_flutter/src/blocs/stories_provider_bloc.dart';
import 'package:new_flutter/src/models/item_model.dart';

class NewsListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int? itemId;

  const NewsListTile({super.key, this.itemId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = StoriesProvider.of(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.items,
        builder:
            (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Future<ItemModel?>>> snapshot) { 
print(snapshot);
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text('Streams still loading');
          }
          return FutureBuilder(
            future: snapshot.data![itemId],
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel?> itemSnapshot) {
              if (!itemSnapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('Still loading item $itemId');
              }
              return Text(itemSnapshot.data!.title);
            },
          );
        });
  }
}

and this is the news list class, respectfully :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_flutter/src/blocs/stories_provider_bloc.dart';
import 'package:new_flutter/src/widgets/news_list_tile.dart';

class NewsList extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewsList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = StoriesProvider.of(context);

    ///This is bad!!! don't do this.
    ///Temporary
    bloc.fetchTopIds();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        elevation: 5,
        title: const Text(
          'Top News',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: buildList(bloc),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(StoriesBloc bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.topIds,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          );
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
            bloc.fetchItem(snapshot.data![index]);

            return NewsListTile(
              itemId: snapshot.data![index],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


This is the result of the print statement in the console area.
I/flutter (12279): AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Future<ItemModel?>>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)
D/EGL_emulation(12279): app_time_stats: avg=124.70ms min=3.45ms max=1238.71ms count=16
I/flutter (12279): AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Future<ItemModel?>>>(ConnectionState.active, null, type 'Future<ItemModel?>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<ItemModel>' of 'value', #0      _LinkedHashMapMixin.[]= (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:513:30)
I/flutter (12279): #1      StoriesBloc._itemsTransformer.<anonymous closure> (package:new_flutter/src/blocs/stories_bloc.dart:32:14)
I/flutter (12279): #2      _ScanStreamSink.add (package:rxdart/src/transformers/scan.dart:13:42)
I/flutter (12279): #3      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)
I/flutter (12279): #4      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
I/flutter (12279): #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:365:11)
I/flutter (12279): #6      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:541:14)
I/flutter (12279): #7      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:646:11)
I/flutter (12279): #8      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:617:7)
I/flutter (12279): #9      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
I/flutter (12279): #10     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_micr
I/flutter (12279): AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Future<ItemModel?>>>(ConnectionState.active, null, type 'Future<ItemModel?>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<ItemModel>' of 'value', #0      _LinkedHashMapMixin.[]= (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:513:30)

This is repository class
import 'package:new_flutter/src/models/item_model.dart';
import 'package:new_flutter/src/resources/news_api_provider.dart';
import 'package:new_flutter/src/resources/news_db_provider.dart';

class Repository {
  List<Source> sources = <Source>[
    newsDbProvider,
    NewsApiProvider(),
  ];

  List<Cache> caches = <Cache>[
    newsDbProvider,
  ];

  Future<List<int>> fetchTopIds() {
    return sources[1].fetchTopIds();
  }

  Future<ItemModel?> fetchItems(int id) async {
    ItemModel? item;
    Source source;

    for (source in sources) {
      item = await source.fetchItem(id);
      break;
    }

    for (var cache in caches) {
      cache.addItem(item!);
    }
    return item;
  }
}

abstract class Source {
  Future<List<int>> fetchTopIds();

  Future<ItemModel?> fetchItem(int id);
}

abstract class Cache {
  Future<int> addItem(ItemModel item);
}

final newsDbProvider = NewsDbProvider();


Nested builders probably suffer in the same way as this: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

what do you see if you add print(snapshot); before line if (!snapshot.hasData) { ?

I have edited my question to add the print statement at the end.

as you can see: AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Future<ItemModel?>>>(ConnectionState.active, null, type 'Future<ItemModel?>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<ItemModel>' of 'value', #0      _LinkedHashMapMixin.[]= (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:513:30) you have an error in your stream - it is stored in snapshot.error, also in the log you posted you can see the exact code location where it occurred (also available with snapshot.stackTrace)

I still don't get it

StoriesBloc._itemsTransformer.<anonymous closure> (package:new_flutter/src/blocs/stories_bloc.dart:32:14) - the error occurred in file blocs/stories_bloc.dart, line 32 column 14

are you willing to help me out or stress me more? cause I am really looking for a solution here and you pointing out more errors. I have reviewed that line of code and corrected, it gets worse.so if you really know what I need, why don't you solve it and show it to me

how can i say anything if i even dont know what is the line number 32 in blocs/stories_bloc.dart?

did you read my entire question and the codes that followed?, I pasted stories bloc class over there and that line is the function _itemsTransformer

done that... still giving me these insane errors:
Instance of 'Future<ItemModel?>', 42098471: Instance of 'Future<ItemModel?>', 42137527: Instance of 'Future<ItemModel?>', 42106368: Instance of 'Future<ItemModel?>', 42089611: Instance of 'Future<ItemModel?>', 42141587: Instance of 'Future<

and this one :
E/flutter (17949): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(UNIQUE constraint failed: Items.id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)) sql 'INSERT INTO Items (id, type, "by", time, text, parent, url, score, title, descendants, dead, deleted, kids) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' args [0, , , 0, , 0, , 0, , 0, 0, 0, []]
E/flutter (17949): #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite_platform_interface/src/platform_exception.dart:12:7)
E/flutter (17949): 

forget bout .pipe() it has nothing to do with the error. it only takes the stream subscription and points it to a target destination. I have done something but I have now moved from one progress to another with errors.

what does Repository.fetchItems() return?

which class are you referring to

Repository.fetchItems what type does it return?

I have added that entire class so you look at it. but it fetches the items from the item model class

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Ah overkill for a rather simple task. Why not just use a library like flutter_bloc instead?

well sometimes I love a little challenge, I am also watching a tutorial dated 2018 or 2019, and it intrigued me, the challenge is being able to traverse the deprecations and follow the instructions without breaking formation. I am OCD like that
